# Replace letter only if found at start of word in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I couldn't find a definite answer to this so I am posting a question.

I would like to add some bbcode to letters in every word in my string but only when the letter is found at the start of a string. It should add to both upper and lower case letters at start of words.

For example it would replace:

```
string s = "Alan ate an apple";
```

With:

```
[bbcode]A[/bbcode]lan [bbcode]a[/bbcode]te [bbcode]a[/bbcode]n [bbcode]a[/bbcode]pple
```

cant' figure out how to achieve this :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search regex:

```
(\b[Aa])
```

Replace by:

```
[bbcode]$1[/bbcode]
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ9tC3/2)

Here search regex is: `(\b[Aa])` which is matching letter `a` or `A` only after a word boundary `\b` thus matching only the first letter of a word.

Comment: Awesome, although I should have mentioned that for each case I would like to replace only a specific letter, rather than any letter of the alphabet. So in my previous example I would like to replace the letter A/a.

Comment: I have indeed used `Alan ate an apple` in my demo which produces: `[bbcode]A[/bbcode]lan [bbcode]a[/bbcode]te [bbcode]a[/bbcode]n [bbcode]a[/bbcode]pple` as output. Check demo link again.

Comment: thank you anubhava. Sorry I might have given a bad example. Lets say: "Alan ate a banana". It would only replace words starting with A or a. Rather than any letter of the alphabet. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough